# How to create an index in a data frame based on another data frame in R

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

I am trying to create an index in DF1 based off of DF2. In DF2 I have a column called ID, and what I want to do is search DF1$Name and if it contains a value from DF2$Wine then to fill in the ID from DF2$ID to DF1$ID.

DF1 = allwines

```
a <- c("Malbec", "Syrah", "Cabernet Sauvignon", "Merlot")
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
allwines <- data.frame(a, b)

> allwines
                   a b
1             Malbec 1
2              Syrah 2
3 Cabernet Sauvignon 3
4             Merlot 4
```

DF2 = wines

```
c <- c("Charles Smith", "K Vintners", "K Vintners", "Two Vintners", "K Vintners", "Kerloo", "Betz Family", "Efeste" )
d <- c("Royal City Syrah", "Cattle King Syrah", "Klein Syrah", "Make Haste Cinsault", "The Hidden Syrah", "Stone Tree Malbec", "Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon", "Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon")
wines <- data.frame(c, d)

> wines
              c                             d
1 Charles Smith              Royal City Syrah
2    K Vintners             Cattle King Syrah
3    K Vintners                   Klein Syrah
4  Two Vintners           Make Haste Cinsault
5    K Vintners              The Hidden Syrah
6        Kerloo             Stone Tree Malbec
7   Betz Family Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon
8        Efeste   Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon
```

Desired Output

```
> desired
              c                             d ID
1 Charles Smith              Royal City Syrah  2
2    K Vintners             Cattle King Syrah  2
3    K Vintners                   Klein Syrah  2
4  Two Vintners           Make Haste Cinsault NA
5    K Vintners              The Hidden Syrah  2
6        Kerloo             Stone Tree Malbec  1
7   Betz Family Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon  3
8        Efeste   Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon  3
```

My attempts have just been generating an ID row full of NA. 
The idea is to search through the wine names in the wines row, and match them with wines from allwines, for example Syrah from allwines$a would match Royal City Syrah, Cattle King Syrah, and Klein Syrah in wines$d

Comment: In your data, `sum(unique(df1$Name) %in% unique(df2$Wine))` gives zero. So, it not expected to find any matching rows to join/merge. Alternatively, `intersect(unique(df1$Name), unique(df2$Wine))` gives empty vector.

Comment: can you change your data frames so that some of the `DF2$Wine`s actually match up with `DF1$Name`s?

Comment: try `idx <- sapply(DF2$Wine, function(x) DF1$Name[grep(x, DF1$Name, ignore.case = TRUE)]); DF1$ID <- DF2$ID[match(names(idx[match(DF1$Name, idx)]), DF2$Wine)]` maybe. I made some test cases and it seems okay

Comment: @rawr it is still producing NA in the DF1$ID, but the first part that creates idx seems to be working

Comment: @JamieLeigh all are NAs or only some? if there are no matches, `match` returns NA, eg `match(1,2)`

Comment: @rawr all are NAs, When I run the first line it does half of what I want, `idx <- sapply(allwines$Wine, function(x) Wines$Name[grep(x, Wines$Name, ignore.case = TRUE)])` I get a list of all wines from Wines that match each wine in allwines ex: ` $ Albariño                    : chr [1:7] " Estate Vineyard Albariño " " Albariño " " Albariño " " Albariño " ...`  I just need to figure out how to apply the ID field from allwines to a new ID field in Wines

Comment: @JamieLeigh try `idx <- trimws(idx)` then use the grepping. also the grepping will only look for an exact match of the wines, so you might have to use `agrep` or some fuzzy matching if the wines do not match the names exactly

Answer (score 0):

If the names match up exactly between df2$Wine and df1$Name, you can simply join on those columns to obtain what you want.

Before you create the list of all NAs, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
newdf <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c('Name', 'Wine'))
```

newdf should now contain all of the original rows from df1, and the corresponding ID if it is found in df2.

This is assuming, of course, that everything is formatted correctly and that the names match.

Comment: I'm not looking for exact matches though, what I want to do is if Wines$Name **contains** allwines$Wine it will put the ID number in. Since the names in Wines$Name are unique, such as Royal City Syrah, I would want that to match with Syrah from allwines$Wine.

Comment: Ok, could you edit your question to reflect that? Also, perhaps providing an example where an output would be expected would help (in the current case, there are no similarities).